# Mysql EXECUTE USING null...?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, sql-null

Is there any way to set a variable in mysql so that it **equals** NULL?

I'm trying to write a system for managing persistent prepared statements on multiple connection pools. I'm doing PREPARE / SET / EXECUTE directly on a database. For instance:

```
PREPARE test FROM 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?';
SET @email='me@me.com';
EXECUTE test USING @email;
```

The problem is, if you set `@email=NULL` it won't pick up rows where email was null. You'd have to use the `<=>` operator for that. The trouble is, this statement only works with equality and can't use a null-safe operator:

```
PREPARE test FROM 'UPDATE users SET email=?';
```

In other words, I need a way to ALWAYS use `=` or always use `<=>` in mixed prepared statements that may include select / where, update / set, etc., so I can bind the value NULL freely to any parameter... ideally without demanding that the consumer always use a null-safe equality in their WHERE if a null (or not null) might end up being bound.

So I think my question is how to define a variable so that it equals NULL, or doesn't equal NULL, in a way that can be used in comparisons *without the null-safe operator*. Is that possible in Mysql?

Edit:
Just to add, as of now the only way I can see getting around this would be trying to parse where I am in the statement and find out if I'm behind a WHERE or behind a SET, and replace = with <=> in the former instance. That seems insane for what I'm trying to do...

Comment: If you have additional points to add, put them in the question, not a comment.

Comment: You could use `WHERE (? IS NULL AND email IS NULL) OR email = ?`

Comment: There's no way around the fact that `NULL` is a special value and can't be tested with `=`.

Comment: And yet one can set `\`col\`=NULL` ... I guess I'm wondering, how does mysqli do this in PHP? Or node-mysql? Both of those allow one to bind a null value in a comparison "prepared" with `=` ...is that just in their own middleware layer replacing them with null-safes?

Comment: Assigning is different from comparing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're wrong about mysqli allowing that, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: Re: the IS NULL method... yes that would work but it would double the number of USING vars passed and it would need to be patched into only the comparison portions of the query, so it doesn't get around the problem of having to parse whether we're in compare or set.

Comment: PDO allows it, for sure.

Comment: Another phrasing might be, since `=` is both the comparison and set operator in SQL for everything other than NULL, shouldn't there be some way to create a constant for NULL?

Comment: I just tried it with PDO, it didn't work.

Comment: The whole reason they created the `<=>` operator is because you can't do this with `=`.

Comment: Unless you want to write a SQL parser that can figure out which `=` are in comparisons and which are in assignments, you're just going to have to bite the bullet and tell your users to use `<=>` in their comparisons.

Comment: @Barmar stated the obvious: you cannot use = to do a null-safe comparison. For better or worse, mysql implemented a separate operator for this. Your users write incorrect sql statements (or ones that do not fully comply with their requirements), then it is up to them to correct it.

Comment: Okay, but how do existing libraries that use prepared statements allow you to bind null values to comparisons, in exactly the same way you bind them to assignments? PDO lets you assign NULL to a binding in an `=` comparison. Is it parsing to know if you're comparing?

Comment: Yes, PDO lets you *assign* NULL to a binding. Your code does **exactly the same**. So why do you complain at all?

Comment: Ah! Okay. Thank you guys. 100% right. PDO lets you bind null assignments but not null compares! I never realized that distinction; it never came up in everyday code. Now I'm trying to build an engine that uses the same prepared query thousands of times with various bindings... so usually a consumer is looking for `WHERE \`x\`=3` but occasionally a they may want to query for `WHERE \`x\` IS NULL` and I don't want to write a whole separate prepared statement using `IS NULL` for every possible case. It seems some kind of parser might be the only way.

Comment: when you finish that task, you'd be very disappointed by the error that tells you something like "the prepared statement has stalled and needs to be prepared again". then eventually  you will drop the idea entirely

Comment: It kills the connection and re-prepares if it fails [and deallocates as needed] ;)

Comment: if you feel like throwing some shade at it, https://github.com/joshstrike/StrikeDB ...it's a work in progress but I'd be happy to get feedback.